# WAMP sites not loading on IPV4 address on LAN devices

Tags: wamp

Ok so I've spent several hours trying to troubleshoot this and I've come up empty handed. This is the basic rundown:

- WAMP on Windows 64 bit, latest WAMP version (PHP 5.4 / Apache 2.4.4)
- I've setup wamp to use C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
- All sites work fine, I wrote this tutorial a few years ago and it all still works: http://kintek.com.au/blog/configuring-multiple-domains-within-wamp-for-local-development/
- When I check my IPV4 with command prompt (ipconfig) it tells me to use 192.168.0.12
- In the past (1+ year ago) on an old version of WAMP I could type this into any devices on the same network and the site would load. Now even on my own machine I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

I've read probably 50 to 100 sites and blog posts giving slightly different ways to fix this. The most common I've seen is open:

In: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf find  and change "Deny from All" to "Allow from All". I've tried probably 20+ different ways of doing this, removing certain files, adding others, trying plenty of permutations of 'add this' or 'try this'. Nothing works.

Whenever I change "Deny from all" to "Allow from all", instead of the "Forbidden error", I get a "This webpage is not available" - Error code: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

All I want to do is load my site up on my phone, does anyone have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Maurice, Start by reading this set of corrections for the 2.4 release published on the WAMPServer forum. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,118138 Especially the Apache stuff, as the syntax for Apache security has change in Apache 2.4.x

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read through the entire thing and did everything relevant. I pretty much updated everything except some of the changes to PHP modules as I use some specific stuff, and IPV4 still doesn't work. Instead of a 'forbidden', error, I now get a 'could not find'. So not sure what that means but I still can't use it on the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Using your more than slightly flawed examples in the publication you mention above here is a suggested solution

By the way, `Allow from all` is not a solution, its the result of not actually understanding what you are doing.
If you have used it, revert those changes to how the system was delivered, especially if you changed this section of the config to Allow from all. `<Directory />` as this allows access to the root folder of the drive you installed WAMPServer onto to the whole world!!!!

Start point from your blog

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain.com.au
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/domain.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache 2 2 Corrections

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain.com.au
    ServerAlias domain.com.au
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/domain.com"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/domain.com">
        Order Deny, Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1  
        # Allow access from any ip within your local subnet
        Allow from 192.168.0
    <Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache 2.4 mods

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain.com.au
    ServerAlias domain.com.au
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/domain.com"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/domain.com">
        # Allow access from 127.0.0.1 and localhost and ::1
        Require local  
        # Allow access from any ip within your local subnet
        Require ip 192.168.0
    <Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```